# WebGL / Three.js shaders what does .r and .g mean?

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, webgl

So im learning shaders by example and I often see .r and .g, what do those two letters mean?

I dont even have an idea what to google since I am unaware of the terminology and use of those two letters G and R when used inside a GL shader program.

```
vec2 uvNoiseTimeShift = vUv + noiseScale * vec2( noiseGeneratorTimeShift.r,
                                                 noiseGeneratorTimeShift.g );
```

When replacing r with g the effect seems to be the same, so im not sure what those properties are for.

Comment: [this covers some of those things](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-shaders-and-glsl.html)

Comment: The accepted answer would make more sense if they said that "r" means red, and "g" means blue. Its a GLSL way to access the R, G, B, and A(lpha) of a vector. X, Y, Z, and W can also be used in their place because they mean the same thing, the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th element of a vector.

Comment: @beiller wow that was very useful. Thanks. Is there a reason why they chose x,y,z,w as alternatives?

Comment: The underlying data format of colors and vertex positions are the same, an array of floating point numbers. So it's for convenience, and you can use xyz when doing vector math, and rgb when dealing with colors in your code.

Comment: @beiller thats was extremely useful. By the way beiller, you might be interested in my newest question regarding mipmapping stackoverflow.com/questions/34040978/mipmap-a-planet-in-three-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This are so-called [swizzle operators](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling) and return the corresponding component of a vector, where `r` corresponds to `x` and so on.

Comment: So x and y is just named differently in webgl?

Comment: What I dont understand in this article is why we need them

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use `myVec.x` or `myVec.r` or `myVec.s` or even `myVec[0]`. They all return or set the same value. It's just a nicer way to access the components of a vector.

Comment: I really thank for for this information, especially the terminology as I am now able to further deepen my knowledge. Also hopefully it helps other users. I need to wait 5 more minutes in order to accept your answer

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations#Components